# Custom cell animation not working in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

So I built a custom animation that makes the cell go off screen to the left (similar to how deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: with UITableViewRowAnimationLeft looks). I did this because if i try to bulk delete(delete all rows in the table) using the classic method(deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: with UITableViewRowAnimationLeft) does not look right. Now my custom animation looks and works great. I have different menu buttons that first clear the table using my animation and it works great. The thing is I want the same animation to kick in when i select a cell in the table but for some reason it just doesn't work (no animations kick in). Here's the animation code tho it should be redundant(this code get's called for each cell-- from the last to the first row):

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
CGRect newFrame;

if(i%2==0){
    newFrame = cell.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}else{
    newFrame = cell.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:0
                 animations:^{cell.frame = newFrame;}
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                     //[cell removeStatus];
                     if(i == 0){

                         [dataSource removeAllObjects];
                         [_table reloadData];
                     }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to this question. I switched the animations to basic animation and now it works.